# Detect which form has been submitted in C#/ASP.NET

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have two forms on the same webpage and I would like to detect which one was submitted upon a post event and show a different message dependant on the submitted form.

I have seen a few examples where people have detected this based on which submit button was clicked, but in my case the form could be submitted by simply pressing enter. Is it possible to detect which form was submitted based on the form name/id? If this can not be done, what would be the best approach for this?

Here is my code in it's simplest form, I think the syntax I've used is for when using submit buttons, but I included it just incase I was wrong:

```
<form method="post" name="form1" id="form1">
    <input type="text" name="textbox1" />
</form>

<form method="post" name="form2" id="form2">
    <input type="text" name="textbox2"  />
</form>

if(IsPost){
    if(Request["submit"] == "form1"){
        <p>Form 1 was submitted</p>
    }else if(Request["submit"] == "form2"){
        <p>Form 2 was submitted</p>
    }
}
```

Comment: You could place a hidden field in each form that contains a unique name

Comment: I don't think you should be using multiple forms at all.

Comment: If you are going to use multiple forms, you should give them separate actions / destinations. the route you're currently taking makes it harder to debug and more error prone.

Comment: just out of interest, why shouldn't you use multiple forms on one page? I'm currently using a login form (which is on every page) and also a contact form on one page, so these eventually end up on the same page.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could place a hidden field in each form that holds a unique name for the form:

```
<form method="post" name="form1" id="form1">
    <input type="text" name="textbox1" />
    <input type="hidden" name="Form1Submitted" value="true" />
</form>

<form method="post" name="form2" id="form2">
    <input type="text" name="textbox2"  />
    <input type="hidden" name="Form2Submitted" value="true" />
</form>
```

Then you could check it in your codebehind like this:

```
if(IsPost){
    if(Request["Form1Submitted"] == "true"){
        <p>Form 1 was submitted</p>
    }else if(Request["Form2Submitted"] == "true"){
        <p>Form 2 was submitted</p>
    }
}
```